# How do I run a method Boolean: checkUserName(); This method ensures that any username contains an under score (_) and is no more than 5 characters

Tags: java, variables, methods, global

This is the code, that I have so far. It does not run. The method does not seem to be taking the input string and processing it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    boolean checkUserName(){
        boolean underscore; // declaring boolean variable(True or False)
        //if statement, conditional 
        underscore=userName.contains("_");//checking if the userName does indeed contain an Underscore(_)
        if (userName.length()<5 && underscore==true) {
            System.out.println("Username successfully captured");    
        
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner name1 = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter username");
        String userName;
        userName= name1.nextLine(); // Read user input
        checkUserName(userName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

1. `checkUserName` has to be static, because it is called directly by a static method, in this case your main method.
2. `checkUserName` needs an input
3. 'userName.length()<5' means any number less than 5, 5 is not less than 5
4. `checkUserName` expects a boolean return, if you dont need a return change it to void.
5. try to give better names, for example `hasUnderscore` would be better than `underscore`

   ```
   static boolean checkUserName(String userName) {
       boolean underscore = userName.contains("_");
       if (userName.length() <= 5 && underscore == true) {
           System.out.println("Username successfully captured");
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner name1 = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
       System.out.println("Enter username");
       String userName;
       userName = name1.nextLine(); // Read user input
       checkUserName(userName);

   }
   ```

Welcome to Java